# Jenkins job retrigger himself

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I have jenkins and bitbucket. When I make a commit to branch "A" one bitbucket webhook trigger a job on jenkins. If job complete success it should make commit to bitbucket branch "A". When jenkins make commit to bitbucket branch A he triggers a job and this cycle doesn't stop. Please help

Comment: You need to improve your webhook. Example: Run the webhook only if the commiter was not jenkins or another specific user.

Comment: But I don't know how I should do it. Do you know? can you discribe this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Open postman once it has been installed and then click on the Request option in the Building Blocks section. It will prompt you for some details like name and description. If no collection is present click on +Create Collection to create one.

Once you enter the details hit Save. It should now display a screen similar to the screenshot below.
Clicking on GET will allow you to change the HTTP request type. Click on GET and select the POST option.

Comment: Perhaps you could add screenshots to help describe what you're saying.